# Dynamics GP Web Services: Any way to get a list of companies that a GP user has access to?

Tags: dynamics-gp

Is there any way, through use of the GP web services that you can retrieve a list of companies that a specified GP user has access to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using GPConnection with Microsoft Dexterity.
Thanks though Tim.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend econnect, one the ways it can be extended is to create custom Transaction Requester.

The requester information can be found here;
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625137.aspx

Thus you could use a view or staging table (I can't remember if views are allowed) to reach the user access table you are after and then access it though a custom requester.

Comment: I have zero experience using eConnect, could you give me some more detail?